# How to add new item to my list using C#?

Tags: c#, image, list

I have an application that generates bitmap images each time I run the application. However each time I run the application it generates a new series of bmp images after each other and I am trying to add bitmap images to my list but I have difficulty as after I add items to my list, I cannot see anything in the list.

Comment: Are you aware of what a process is? Once a process (your application) terminates, all memory associated with it is freed. If you want to retain a list of bitmaps generated across executions of your application, you're going to need to persist the list to storage of some kind, then read it in on application startup.

Comment: i just want to know if the way i am declaring the list and adding a new item to the list and also going through the list and display it is correct or not?

Comment: Please explain what “I cannot see anything in the list” and “display it is correct”  mean.

Comment: “I cannot see anything in the list” means there is nothing in the list! and the list is actually empty. also "correct" refers to the second part of my question;). I mean is that code correct or not? hope this is clear;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach loop would result in the last item in the list to be saved and displayed.

If that is intended, you might as well use `list1[list1.Count() -1]`.